# unexpected behavior of push/pull sockets in netmq (zeromq)

Tags: sockets, zeromq, netmq

I am trying to use netmq (the port of zeroMQ). Here is the problem I found. Here is a code:

```
class Program
{
    private static NetMQContext context;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        context = NetMQContext.Create();
        using (var puller = context.CreatePullSocket())
        {
            puller.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5651");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Task.Run(new Action(PusheThread));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("any key to start receive");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Msg msg = new Msg();
            msg.InitEmpty();
            for (; puller.TryReceive(ref msg, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)); msg = new Msg(), msg.InitEmpty())
            {
                var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Data);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("any");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void PusheThread()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine("started: " + guid);
        using (var pusher = context.CreatePushSocket())
        {
            pusher.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5651");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                pusher.Send("helo! " + guid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we run this code and watch in console we saw some messages was lost.
Like:

```
any key to start receive
started: 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
started: 4211d77a-ad9f-40f1-9382-121156325128
started: bd735e75-2692-4abe-b8b1-fbddbe21e546
started: 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
started: 281ff59e-4430-4fc6-9435-4dc2c5e6015e
helo! 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
helo! 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
helo! 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
helo! 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
helo! 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
helo! 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
helo! 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
helo! 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
helo! 8aeca8e5-ed41-4055-ab72-750a0e61a680
helo! 6749d3bb-6b2b-4caa-b22e-755dba4d932d
any
```

As we see where is no messages from `4211d77a-ad9f-40f1-9382-121156325128`, `bd735e75-2692-4abe-b8b1-fbddbe21e546` and some another.
Is the problem in multithreading? Or I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check for errors connecting and sending in your pusher threads, see if anything pops up.

Comment: I have found this issue exists only in `netmq`. If I using native `zeromq` .net wrapper all works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `PusheThread` where you simple kill of the newly created `PushSocket` to fast.

```
static void PusheThread()
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine("started: " + guid);
    using (var pusher = context.CreatePushSocket())
    {
        pusher.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5651");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pusher.Send("helo! " + guid);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Even though this isn't a solid solution, it should prove that the problem is the `PushSocket` is disposed by the `using` statement before being able to send the messages.

That some messages even through just shows how fast NetMQ and ZeroMQ is :)